# TypeError: GetSize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.7, pyspin

I am getting the following error iwht below code:

> TypeError: GetSize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
import PySpin

system = PySpin.System.GetInstance()
cam_list = system.GetCameras()

# This works:

numCams  = cam_list.GetSize()

# this fails:

numCams  = PySpin.CameraList.GetSize()

print ("No. of cams: ", numCams)
```

Why?

Edit:

```
class myMain(object):
    def main(self):
        numCams  = PySpin.CameraList.GetSize()
        print ("No. of cams: ", numCams)
```

Comment: Because `GetSize` is not a static method (i.e., it takes `self` (an instance of the class) as its first input parameter).

Comment: I am using it in a method from a class but still not working.

Comment: It doesn't matter where **you're** using it. It's how the function itself is implemented in the `PySpin` module.

Comment: how then to procede because adding self isn't the answer? If I run it like `numCams  = PySpin.CameraList.GetSize` I get this annoying `No. of cams :  <function CameraList.GetSize at 0x00000214A3228158>`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your question. You seem to already have a way to get it done (under the `This works` comment). Why exactly are you in the need of getting it to work in a different way? It's kinda like asking "why can't I get this function to run when I add an under-scrore at the end?".

Comment: The library has a limited set of examples and I need to run certain functions which I can't seem to get working. The wrapper made for the library seem to be non-pythonicly made but I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe that `CameraList` is a class, and that `GetSize` is a **non-static** method in that class. If I'm right, then `CameraList.GetSize()` should obviously not work because you're trying to call the method using the class itself, but `CameraList().GetSize()` should, because you'll be creating an **instance of the class** and then using it in order to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing it before you call it

```
cams = PySpin.CameraList()
numCams = cams.GetSize()
print ("No. of cams: ", numCams)
```

Comment: Or `numCams = PySpin.CameraList().GetSize()` in one line if you don't need to reuse this instance

Comment: I tried to get it running with `PySpin().CameraList().GetSize().. skipping the () from `PySpin` did the trick.